# Deleting SocialComment / Note using object model

Tags: social

The CommentId Property of SocialComment is marked as Internal. How can I then delete a specific SocialComment given an ID?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this problem? If yes, could you post the answer?

Comment: No I havent found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int GetCommentID(SocialComment comment)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(SocialComment).GetProperty("CommentID", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        return int.Parse(propertyInfo.GetValue(comment, null).ToString());
    }
```

p.s.  it's very good worked for me. hope, this help you too :)

Comment: Nice. Did not know that was possible.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell it is not possible to get the id. But it is possible to delete by using the url and title instead (optionally also the comment text). Not optimal but it will work for most scenarios.